# In java, what happens when deleting an object while it is being used?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, hashtable

Here is the scenario:

1. I have a java Hashtable that takes a String as a key and an object as the value.
2. One thread gets the object by using the key and calls a method on this object.
3. while the method is doing some operation from step b), another thread calls the remove on that particular key which references the object.

What happens then ?

Should I put a lock on the operation itself ?

Comment: Note that it is not possible to "delete" an object in Java; only the garbage collector can do that. If *all* references to an object go out of scope, the GC can then recover the used memory as it sees fit.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing happens, assuming you're talking about a (thread-safe) `java.util.Hashtable`. Removing the object from the `Hashtable` has no impact on *other* references to that object.

Objects are only eligible for garbage collection once *nothing* references them.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Hashtable class.  So in other words, the operation from that one thread will complete before the object gets removed ?

Comment: Incorrect. The object will be removed from the hashtable _completely independently_ of the method being called on that object.

Comment: got it thanks... so the reference from the hashtable is removed, but the reference from the thread still goes ahead and completes the operation. At that point, that object would be eligible for GC because it is not being referenced anymore....

Comment: @user2001996 Either the `remove` happens first (so `get` returns null) or the `get` happens first (so it doesn't).

Comment: @immibis in the scenario described in the question, it appears that the `remove()` call happens strictly after the `get()`.

Comment: @MattBall Oh, right. The question is worded unclearly.

Comment: @immibis got it.  so either it gets or it does not.  Once it gets, the reference is acquired, then it can operate independently of other references.

Comment: sorry about the ambiguity in the working.. No, I don't know which one would come first.  So yes, I need to check if the reference that gets obtained from the thread is null or not.   thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The method itself references the object. If you can see a object, you see it thru a reference.

Answer (score 1):

The logic will complete and the object will be removed from the table although the state of the table may be inaccurate depending on when your threads read from the table.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Hashtable class.  So in other words, the operation from that one thread will complete before the object gets removed ?

Comment: It does not matter that the object gets removed, the object is acquired through a reference and the logic will complete on that object.

Comment: thanks, got it.. basically when the thread gets the object from calling the "get" method of the hashtable, it is acquired through a reference, and when the hashtable's remove gets called, it only removes the reference from the hashtable perspective when has nothing to do with the reference acquired from the thread.  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @user2001996 yes you are. Glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete objects in Java. The reason you don't run out of memory is that the garbage collector will delete them for you, when you're not looking - which means that if there's any way you could tell the object was deleted, it won't be deleted. (Apart from things designed for that purpose, like `finalize` and `WeakReference`).

Removing an object from a Hashtable only affects the Hashtable; it has *no effect whatsoever* on the actual object, and in particular it doesn't delete the object.

Answer (score 0):

What happens actually depends on more than what you've specified. In particular, unless step 2 has a [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) relationship with step 3, it's entirely possible for the value to have been removed from your map before step 2 starts.

Assuming the data structure in step 3 is thread-safe (which `Hashtable` is) there will be no issue with step 3; it will successfully remove the entry.  However step 2 may run into problems without explicit locking. For example, if you call `containsKey()` before calling `get()`, and step 3 happens to run in-between these two calls, step 2's behavior will be inconsistent. This is called a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

There are numerous ways to ensure a happens-before relationship (one of which is indeed with locking) but exactly what you need will depend on your requirements.

As an aside, there is little benefit to using `Hashtable`; it is an old, slow `Map` implementation that has no particular benefits over standard alternatives.

If your mapped data will be accessed by only one thread (or you'll enforce synchronous access with custom locking) use a `HashMap`. If your mapped data will be shared between threads, use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.